# How to read a word and then take in input in java?

Tags: java, tostring

So im trying to create a program that reads a word and then sets of 2 numbers that specify rectangles, (w, h). When the word is “area”, the program should calculate and print the area. When the word is “perimeter”, calculate and print the perimeter. When the word is “quit”, exit the program, without reading the numbers.

The output should look like this:

```
java Rectangle1
? area 1 2 3 4
Area of (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) = 12.0
? perimeter 1 2 3 4
Perimeter of (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) = 14.0
? area 2 3 4 5
Area of (2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0) = 20.0
? quit
$
```

I am able to get the program to store the width and height first and then read area or perimeter so it looks like this:

```
$ java Rectangle1
To find the area or perimeter of a rectangle
Enter the Length from 1 to 20 ( defaults to 1 ) : 
1
Enter the Width from 1 to 20 (defaults to 1 ) : 
2
Enter 1 to find Area
Enter 2 to find Perimeter
Enter 3 to quit
Choice:1
Area: 2.000000
Choice:2
Perimeter: 6.000000
Choice:3
```

But I am not sure how to get it to read the word area or perimeter and then on the same line take in the width and height then print out either area of perimeter as an answer until quit is entered

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//I just put everything in one class, the Rectangle keeps its properties
//main was just added
//feel free to seperate as needbe

public class Rectangle1{
// length and width default to 1
private static double length;
private static double width;
public static double perimeter;
public static double area;
private static int choice;

//empty constructor
public Rectangle1(){
    setLength(1);
    setWidth(1);
}

// constructor with length and width supplied
public Rectangle1( double theLength, double theWidth) { 
    setLength(theLength );
    setWidth( theWidth );
} // end Rectangle two-argument constructor

// validate and set length
public void setLength(double theLength){
    length = ( theLength > 0.0 && theLength < 20.0 ? theLength : 1.0 );
} // end method setLength

// validate and set width
public void setWidth(double theWidth){
    width = ( theWidth > 0.0 && theWidth <20.0 ? theWidth : 1.0);
}//end method setWidth

// get value of length
public double getLength(){
    return length;
}//end method getLength

// get value of width
public double getWidth(){
    return width;
}// end method getWidth

// calculate rectangle's perimeter
public static double calcPerimeter () {
    perimeter = (length * 2) + (width * 2);//calculates area
    System.out.printf("Perimeter: %f\n", perimeter);//output
    return perimeter;
}

// calculate rectangle's area
public static double calcArea(){
    area = (length * width);//calculates area
    System.out.printf("Area: %f\n", area);//output
    return area;
}

// convert to String
public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s02d %02d", length, width);
}///end method toPerimeter String


public static void main( String args[] )
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    Rectangle1 myRectangle = new Rectangle1(); //this is an object instance


    int choice;

    double width;
    double length;


    System.out.println("To find the area or perimeter of a rectangle" );
    System.out.println ( "Enter the Length from 1 to 20 ( defaults to 1 ) : " );
    length = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println ( "Enter the Width from 1 to 20 (defaults to 1 ) : " );
    width = input.nextInt();

    //We need to now set these values to our rectangle object
    myRectangle.setWidth(width);
    myRectangle.setLength(length);

    System.out.println ( "Enter 1 to find Area" );
    System.out.println ( "Enter 2 to find Perimeter" );
    System.out.println ( "Enter 3 to quit" );
    System.out.printf ( "Choice:" );
    choice = input.nextInt();
    while ( choice != 3 ){
        if (choice == 1){
            System.out.printf( "", myRectangle.calcArea()); //call the method of our created object instance, NOT the class name
        }
        else if ( choice == 2){
            System.out.printf( "", myRectangle.calcPerimeter());//call the method of our created object instance, NOT the class name
        }

        System.out.printf ( "Choice:" );
        choice = input.nextInt();
    }
}//end method main
} // end class Rectangle
```

Sorry I know the indenting is not good.

Comment: sorry, i am a bit confused about what your input is. Could you give a sample input and then a sample output? thanks. - i.e. you have some text labeled, "this is the output:" of all that text labeled " this is the output:", what is inputted by the user?

Comment: Have you even tried to understand your program and look at the API of the Scanner class? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html Your program (which I presume you copied from somewhere) is already reading the width and length through `nextInt()` to read the numbers. If you check the API of Scanner, you'll see there are other methods to get other types, such as `next()` which gets a String, which you can then check if it contains `area`.

Comment: So basically the input should be
area 1 2 3 4
and the output should be 
12
Or 
perimeter 1 2 3 4
and the output should be
14

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user for the entire question (ie {cmd} {x} {y} {width} {height}) in one go and then parse this result.

For example...

```
cmd = input.nextLine(); // Where cmd is a String
// example input...
// area 1 2 3 4
// perimeter 1 2 3 4
// quite
```

Once you have the user input, you need to parse this text.  Now you could use regular expression to do this, but better to keep it simple to start with ;)

Instead, you can use what you already know...

```
Scanner parser = new Scanner(cmd);
cmd = parser.next();
// Example output...
// area
// perimeter 
// quite
```

Now.  Once you have the `cmd` (or what the user wants to do), you need to start making decisions about...

```
// First, we need to know if we can handle the question...
if ("area".equalsIgnoreCase(cmd) || "perimeter".equalsIgnoreCase(cmd)) {
```

Then you can start extracting the parameters...

```
int x = parser.nextInt();
int y = parser.nextInt();
int width = parser.nextInt();
int height = parser.nextInt();
```

Now, I'd probably also use `parser.hasInt()` to check that the parameter exists, but that's just me...

Then, all you need to do is stick it inside a loop...

```
do {
    // Get user input
    // Parse user input
    // Make some decisions...
} while (!"quite".equalsIgnoreCase(cmd));
```